# Calling dynamic callback function from an async method in the ScriptingObject of the BrowserControl throws Exception

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm calling a callback function from an async function inside my browser control scripting object. The method is first called from javascript and it tries to callback. For some reason this crashes my application with a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException.

The method looks like this:

```
public void SearchApps(string query, dynamic callback)
{
    ThreadManager.QueryGamesAsync(query, mainForm.Portal, log, 
        (list) =>
        {
            string[] strList = new string[list.Length];
            for(int i = 0; i < strList.Length; i++)
            {
                strList[i] = list[i].Uid;
            }
            string data = json.Serialize(strList);
            callback(data);
        });
}
```

And the Query method looks like this:

```
public static async void QueryGamesAsync(string query, Portal p, Log log, Action<Game.Identifier[]> callback)
{
    callback(await Task.Factory.StartNew<Game.Identifier[]>(() => { return Game.Find(query, p, log); }));
}
```

(I'm using the Microsoft await binding for .Net 4.0 and WinForms with the default browser control)

The full exception looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/it9Mtrak

Edit:

The problem only seems to happen when I call another async function from the Javascript callback function:

```
function searchGames(query)
{
window.external.SearchApps(query,
    function (list)
    {
        var js = JSON.parse(list);
        for (var i = 0; i < js.length; i++) {
            //window.external.Log(js[i]);
            appendAppBox(el, list[i]);

        }
    });
}
```

and

```
function appendAppBox(parent, uid)
{
    window.external.GetAppInfo(uid, function (json) {
        var info = JSON.parse(json);
        parent.innerHTML += getAppBox(info);
        updateAppStatus(uid);
    });
}
```

As you can see, the callback from the search calls appendAppBox, which in turn calls GetAppInfo with another callback function as parameter. Both callback functions work on their own, but the application crashes when they are nested. Why could that be ? I tried invoking the callbacks via the browserControl, didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the issue. Perplexingly a simple js syntax error caused a ton of exceptions up to the point of crashing visual studio. I caught the exception and it turns out HRESULT 0x80020101 points to a simple javascript syntax error in the callback function.